# Equivalent to HorzCenter in order to horizontally center a panel in TMS Web Core?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tms, tms-web-core, horizontal-alignment

In FireMonkey, there's a `HorzCenter` option for the `Align` property on most visual components.

What this does is it horizontally centers the component as well as sets the height to 100%.

In TMS WEB Core, I don't see the `HorzCenter` option for `Align`.

How can I horizontally center my panel in TMS WEB Core? I want to do the same as what `HorzCenter` does in FMX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HorzCenter` is not available in TMS WEB Core at all. If you want to achieve the same alignment as `HorzCenter`, then it needs to be custom coded.

In the form's `OnResize` event, you can write the following code to do a `HorzCenter` align:

```
WebPanel.Align := alNone;
WebPanel.Top := 0;
WebPanel.Height := WebPanel.Parent.Height;
WebPanel.Left := (WebPanel.Parent.Width - WebPanel.Width) div 2;
```

This will behave exactly like `HorzCenter` from FireMonkey